# How to preg_match KRA Pin no

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

While working on a human resource system, I had a problem of validating Kenya Revenue Authority's PinNo. The string should have a length of 11.  The string should start with a letter `a` or `A`, then any number `[0-9]` and end with a character `[a-zA-Z]`.

Here is my implementation:

```
$pattern = '/^\A(a|A){1}\d{9}[a-zA-Z]{1}$/';
$pinno='A012345678K';

if (!(preg_match($pattern, $pinno))) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: @Andreas it was meant to be _start with letter `a` or `A`_

Comment: Yes I noticed that too. It took a while to understand it

Comment: `if (!something) return false; else return true;` is redundant. You can just return `something`, in your case `return preg_match($pattern, $pinno);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may re-vamp your code to

```
$pattern = '/^a\d{9}[a-z]$/i';
return preg_match($pattern, $pinno);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5FHZux/1). The pattern will match:

- `^` - start of string
- `a` - `a` or `A` as `i` is the case insensitive modifier
- `\d{9}` -  nine digits
- `[a-z]` - any ASCII letter
- `$` - end of string.

NOTE:

- `^\A` matches start of string twice, you may keep either of these anchors
- To match a char from a set, it is advised to use *character classes*, so `(a|A)` -> `[aA]`. However, you may use a mere `a` and add the case insensitive modifier
- `{1}` limiting modifier is always redundant as any atom is matched once by default.

A note on `$`: it will also match before a final newline in the string. To avoid that behavior, replace `$` with `\z`, or add a `D` modifier: `'/^a\d{9}[a-z]$/iD'`.